# Changing a raster format and coordinate system: GeoTiff in WGS84 to ASCII in UTM 35N

Tags: qgis, wgs84, utm, grids-graticules, ascii

I have a DEM in GeoTIFF format in EPSG 4326 - WGS84 that I export from WindPro. I want to use the same DEM as input for another wind software that accepts only ARC/INFO ASCII GRID (ascii) format and only Cartesian coordinate systems.

So I need to convert this DEM from GeoTIFF in WGS84 to ASCII in EPSG 32635 - UTM 35N.

I am using QGIS and I tried to reproject it using Wrap(reproject) and then do the transformation of formats using Translate(convert formats). However when doing so, because of the reprojection some pixels on the sides become nodata pixels. This wind software is telling me that there are too many no data pixels and it doesn't allow me to use the file.

[image]

Another thing that I tried was to use the ASCII grid generated in WGS and just change the coordinates of the down-left corner and calculate a new cell size, basically transforming the cell size from degrees to meters. But here I think I'm doing something wrong because it says the file is incorrect and I cannot use it.

[image]

Do you have any idea how could I be doing this?